# new \input{file} Package, Command wrapper: microtype .tex with reserved symbols

Tags: verbatim, input, external-files, parsing

I know enough LaTeX to produce great looking documents. LaTeX makes it more difficult to NOT do that. But I don't advanced LaTeX or TeX or plainTeX or "@" or other advanced, cryptic programming tricks, which I've seen in some .sty files.

From a Root.tex file, I want to input my preamble and then many narrative chapters, all are 100% text (no math, tables or graphics)

Is it possible for ME to create a relatively simple command that works something like \input{filename} does, but can verbatim print most of the special characters, while still typesetting the .tex and/or .txt file in paragraph mode with hyphenation, justification and micro-typography?  I want to allow for thoughtless creation of chapters of narrative with minimal code for formatting occasional text with emphasis or insets.  (I could then let anyone know how they need to write a chapter file, all in a few minutes)

Here's what I want to do, useful to narrative authors:

As many as possible of the reserved characters would print straight-forward, but the **word spacing, linebreaks, paragraph spacing, page breaking and hypenation etc** would all be controlled by LaTeX automation, as usual, and unlike `\verbatim` to take advantage of LaTeX's exceptional typesetting.

This `\newcommand` needs to be able to `\input` and typeset nice looking commercial Novel Chapters as text files that perhaps have stray reserved symbols, left quotations, right quotations, and perhaps other common unicode symbols.

But, using `/input{filename}` balks at paragraphs of text if they contain stray reserved symbols used in literary sentences: **[ # $ % ^ & _ { } ~ \ ]**

So, much like `\input{filename}`, I want to create a new command that could be written called `\incorporate{filename}`, \textinput{filename}, \intake{filename}, \inset{filename}, \ingest{filename}, \absorb{filename} \digest{filename}, \narate{filename} ...whatever.

Here's an example of my root.tex file using `\incorporate{filename}` (it might give an idea how it would be used)

```
%    Novel_1_Root.tex   %
%   %   %   %   %   %   %
\documentclass{book}
\input{LaTeX_Preamble.tex}
\begin{document}
%
\frontmatter
\input{./titlepage.tex}
\input{./copyrightpage.tex}
\input{./dedicationpage.tex}
\maketitle \tableofcontents{}
%
\mainmatter
\chapter{The Blue Hills}
\incorporate{./chapter01.txt}
%                         
\chapter{The Lazy Author}
\incorporate{./chapter02.txt}
%
\chapter{The Car Chase}
\incorporate{./chapter03.txt}
%     etc . . .
%
\end{document}
```

The goal is to create a thoughtless way to write chapters of full of narrative, and to explain to non-LaTeX users how they can written in text files using `\incorporate{filename}`

None of the verbatim packages process the "spaces" and "returns" the way LaTeX processes in paragraph mode, with microtyped literary quality, so straight-off, that won't work for me.

Comment: why call it output if it inputs its argument?

Comment: Did you have a question? Are you looking for people to test your package? Sorry, but right now this reads like 'Here is how I wish LaTeX worked. It would be so much better if my dream were true.' That is, in addition to the fact that (1) there is no question, the implicit question (will somebody create this package of my dreams for me?) is (2) a package request, hence off-topic due to enormity, and (3) a request for an enormous package, hence off-topic due to meta-enormity.

Comment: I'm also puzzled. (1) What does this have to do with unicode? All of the 'symbols' you mention are ASCII. (2) If the pre-processor passes all of those characters on as is, LaTeX will then get them as is, as well. And why have the pre-processor do anything at all with LaTeX code if it is going to pass stuff on to LaTeX anyway? What exactly is the pre-processor supposed to do? As far as I can tell, all it will do is remove excess spaces and blank lines. But why do that since LaTeX does that already?

Comment: @David Carlisle I agree, but I rationalized "output" would be easy to remember because  "\output" outputs a text file, including reserved characters, before it gets processed.  "intake" might be a better choice though ... that or maybe "extract"

Comment: @cfr I thought left quotations and right quotation marks (some of the most common glyphs in novels) were in unicode, but not ascii.  Am I wrong?  The goal is to type reserved glyphs automatically, and unicode glyphs too.

Comment: This would be a one command package.  I need help with the code, and no it doesn't have to be in a package, I can put it all in the preamble.  But since I want to use it in various preambles that have different style settings *(say a style for science fiction, and a style for romance, and one for Adventure etc.) then for convienience Id like to package it, which I can do myself.  How would I write a \newcommand, and what code should I add to the preamble?

Comment: I don't see those mentioned. In any case, why not just use Xe/LuaTeX for those? You don't need anything special for that. I already have `‘’`all over the place in my `.tex` files and I use pdfTeX. But what is meant to happen to the processed file? It doesn't make sense to me at all.

Comment: I don't mean the wanting it as a package makes it enormous. It is the scope of what you seem to want it to do which makes it enormous. The command you want is package-sized. At least, I think so. I still don't really even understand how it is meant to work. On the first run, it does what? Outputs a parsed file? (Why use LaTeX for that?) And then it runs LaTeX on the parsed file? But that's going to include all the crud you protected during the first parsing. It would make sense to me if you wanted to strip those *out*.

Comment: The command would take a txt file (or a tex file), just like /input does, but would process it much like the verbatim environment, except that spaces and returns would not be verbatim.  AND, in the [options] you could type in /output[ /begin{quote}, /end{quote} ]{chapter02.txt} and it would process those LaTeX commands only, everything else would be similar to verbatim, except spaces and returns.

Comment: Suppose chapter02.txt has "#1 He lost the battle but #2 They lost the war." or "$123 dollars", or "He lost 50% of his cash."   BUT, in the chapter02.txt it also has a few things the author did intentionally, writing "/begin{quote} Dear Amanda,  ...  Best Wishes, John. /end{quote}.  **SO** think of it as something that the author of a chapter02.txt file would find as easy as markdown, without having learn LaTeX, only needs to learn the extremely few LaTeX commands necessary, those in the [options].

Comment: btw, /input already accepts my type utf8 chapter.tex files.  It's just that sometimes they crash, and the reason being is that it's a chapter with a "reserved" character.  So, I figured some sort of wrapper could be used with input and or verbatim.  I'm asking here where the expert TeX programmers are.

Comment: one last thing >>And why have the pre-processor do anything at all with LaTeX code if it is going to pass stuff on to LaTeX anyway? What exactly is the pre-processor supposed to do?<<  that's just it, I only want it to do what's in the [options] and not try to process /stuff or %stuff or #stuff etc., just typeset the / # % as glyphs

Comment: What I *think* you want is to read all material given in your `\input` macro with 'safe' category codes (11/12), including normally special characters such as `%` and including ``\``. You then want search-and-replace for a specified set of strings to introduce commands. That's doable if rather slow in classical TeX (read one line at a time) but would be much easier with LuaTeX. ConTeXt has `\asciimode` which is close but still has ``\`` as the escape char. I'd be tempted to examine something akin to that.

Comment: If I'm right, then if you want a complete body of code the question is too broad: much more effort than a couple of paragraphs of text! If you can edit the question to make it a request for general ideas then it might be OK: I could perhaps flesh out the detail a bit. However, an answer of that form is going to assume a good level of TeX knowledge: at present I'm not sure I see that in the question.

Comment: With a slightly different set of requirements it would be a lot easier. For example, if we can leave ``\`` alone but disable a list of known commands (making them output their name) then we can pull things off relatively easily.

Comment: That's fine if variables are tedious in TeX.  Executing  \ and all alpha characters connected to it, plus everything inside { } that's connected to the command.  Maybe execute all these: \{}.  And I especially want spaces and returns just as latex normally adjusts them (not how verbatim always monotypes exactly)  So, I'd like to be able to execute stuff like my newcommand \MyScene, environments, and also anything inside \MyScene{My Stuff} as LaTeX normally obeys.  But, not balk at: "Jack lost 50% on his stock."  or:  "Jill is #1 at..."  or "Joe@go.com"   It's a novel project, with formatting.

Comment: 99% of this long question can be done with `{\catcode\`\%=12 \catcode\`\#=12 \catcode\`\_=12 \input{chapter1.txt}}`

Comment: I really can not guess what you mean by "`\output` outputs a text file" The question is solely concerned with input. Also `\output` is a TeX primitive (concerned with outputting pages, strangely enough:-) so that name is taken.

Comment: Well that ends the "output" debate:-) I was figuring the usage of words like Input and Output as-if relative terms, much like Left or Right for directions: "Take a Left off the interstate on Maple Street, and Walmart is one mile down."  Anyway, the \catcode solves all my problems since I don't need the [options] now, and the typesetting remains superb, just like before.  I like the \textinput command, but will change it to \inputText for myself, But this makes typesetting chapters easier than ever now! BINGO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand\incorporate[1]{{%
\catcode`\$=12
\catcode`\&=12
\catcode`\_=12
\catcode`\^=12
\catcode`\#=12
\catcode`\%=12
\catcode`\~=12
\input{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\section{zzz}

\incorporate{zzz.txt}

\end{document}
```

with input file

```
aaa & bbb is 5% of 4$  but_this_has_underscores


but a blank line is a ‘new para’ with quotes.
```

producing

[image]

Here I have left `\`, `{`, `}` with their latex meanings so they can be used in the file, you can include them in the list of  characters made safe if you wish, so they would just typeset as normal characters.

Conversely you may also want to remove characters from the list made safe for example if you remove `~` then `~` will revert to being a non breaking space marker as in normal latex rather than typeset as `~`.

Allowing or disallowing individual commands would make it vastly more complicated and fragile as `\` would have to be special always and then look ahead to see if the following characters were an allowed command, and if not, back up and insert itself as data. That is unlikely ever to work in a predictable or understandable way.

As noted in comments you can not call the command `\output` as that is a tex primitive, but as this command is concerned solely with input that does not seem too much of a hardship here.